# VB.net Regex grab every line between to strings

Tags: regex, vb.net

Trying to parse a Text file using Regex in Visual Basics using Vb.net

here is a sample text:

> start_Word
>
> vwfedvnrflevn,$%^£$
>
> vfrvnrlwivtn,$%435
>
> wrvrtovrv,vorfewnvoew%T%$2445645
>
> ------------++++++++++++==========
>
> last_Word

so I'm trying to grab into a string all the lines between Start_word and Last_Word

Here is what I have:

```
Dim block As Match = Regex.Match(string, (?s)start_Word(.*?)last_Word, RegexOptions.Multiline)

console.writeline(block.value)
```

I doens't work, how can I make Dotall and Multiline work in VB.Net

Comment: You need just `DOTALL` not `multiline`.

Comment: Yes thats what I'm looking for, how to add DOTALL to vb.net

Answer (score 0):

You could use quantifiers inside lookbehinds in vb.net.

```
(?s)(?<=start_Word[^\n]*\n).*?(?=\n\s*last_Word)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with Look around and `[\w\W]*?` to match multiline

```
(?<=^start_Word)\r?\n[\w\W]*?\r?\n(?=last_Word$)
```

[Online demo](http://regex101.com/r/rT1pJ5/1)

Here `^` is used for start of the line/string and `$` is used for end of the line/string.

You can use `[\d\D]` instead of `[\w\W]` as well.

Comment: Use `@"(?<=^start_Word)\r?\n[\w\W]*?\r?\n(?=last_Word$)"` in C#. I have tested it [HERE](http://derekslager.com/blog/posts/2007/09/a-better-dotnet-regular-expression-tester.ashx)